# move an array if the corresponding values are at the minimum of 5 iterations has a duplicate

Tags: php, arrays, loops

Is there a php code that can move a multidimensional array minimum of 5 iterations if the values has a duplicate?

This is an example code.

```
<?php
  $results = array( 
               array('value'   =>  10),
               array('value'   =>  2),
               array('value'   =>  1),
               array('value'   =>  3),
               array('value'   =>  2), //This will move 
                    array('value'   =>  4),
                    array('value'   =>  5),
                    array('value'   =>  5),  //This will move
                    array('value'   =>  3),  //This will move
                    array('value'   =>  4),  //This will move
                    array('value'   =>  10), //Ok reach minimum of 5 count
                    array('value'   =>  9),
                    array('value'   =>  8),
                    array('value'   =>  7),
                    array('value'   =>  7), // This will move
                    array('value'   =>  8), // This will move
                    array('value'   =>  1), //Ok reach minimum of 5 count
                    array('value'   =>  6), 
                    array('value'   =>  6),  // This will move  
                    array('value'   =>  19) //Ok reach minimum of 5 count               
                    );
                );
?>
```

This is the basic idea. I want to move the values if they found a duplicate within a minimum of 5 iterations. The moving of iterations can move greater than 5.
The data can be random. It will loop to find a better result.
Is this possible?

Here is my expected results. This can be other results that can satisfies the logic.

```
<?php
  $results = array( 
               array(
                    array('value'   =>  6), //Ok
                    array('value'   =>  9), //Ok
                    array('value'   =>  2), //Ok
                    array('value'   =>  7), //Ok
                    array('value'   =>  1), //Ok
                    array('value'   =>  4), //Ok
                    array('value'   =>  8), //Ok
                    array('value'   =>  5), //Ok
                    array('value'   =>  9), //Ok
                    array('value'   =>  2), //Ok
                    array('value'   =>  3), //Ok
                    array('value'   =>  6), //Ok
                    array('value'   =>  4), //Ok
                    array('value'   =>  10), //Ok
                    array('value'   =>  8), //Ok
                    array('value'   =>  7), //Ok
                    array('value'   =>  1), //Ok
                    array('value'   =>  3), //Ok
                    array('value'   =>  5),  //Ok
                    array('value'   =>  10)  //Ok                   
                    );
                );
?>
```

Hope you can help me.

**EDIT:**

Here is my code

```
<?php
$required_array = array();
$temp  = "";     
$temp2 = "";   
foreach($array as $key=>$child) {
    if( $child["value"]==$temp ) {
        $i = $key+5; 
        $required_array[$i] = $child;
    } else {
        $i = $key;
        //if(isset($required_array[$i])) $i++; 
        while(isset($required_array[$i])) { 
            $i++;                           
        }                                  

        $required_array[$i] = $child;   
    }
    $temp  = $child["value"];

}
ksort($required_array); 
print_r($required_array);

//Tried this but always move on five iterations and found duplicate within the range of five
```

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you mean by "move". Can you provide more clear input and output?

Comment: move the value to another row example value 1 if found duplicate between the range of 1 to 5 it will move to another row

Comment: You can't have an array with the same keys for all elements.

Comment: @Jack sorry my mistake forgot to put array on each element. Please check my updated question. Thanks.

Comment: Where do you move the row?  To the end/random position?

Comment: It is very hard to understand what you want to achieve. I thought you meant *remove rows from an array if it has a duplicate within a distance of 5*. But your expected result does not match. Perhaps try providing several smaller examples (eg. with just 12 elements, each example illustrating a different situation). Also, your usage of arrays is unusual, for the sake of clarity, try with arrays of simple integers (e.g. `$res = array(1, 3, 6, 2);`)

Comment: @AbraCadaver every 5 elements. Anyways thanks I got the code correctly now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**array_chunk** solve my issue.

```
<?php
$chunks = array_chunk($array, ceil(count($array)/5));
$array = array();

for($x = 0, $numX =  count($chunks[0]); $x < $numX; $x++){
    for($y = 0, $numY = count($chunks); $y < $numY; $y++){
        if(isset($chunks[$y][$x]))
        //echo $x.' '.$y.'<br>';
        $array[] = $chunks[$y][$x];
    }
}
print_r($array);
?><br>
```

Anyway, my next problem is if I have two rows in an array. Like the example below.

```
<?php
$array   =  array(
                 array('value' => 1, 'value2' => 2),
                 array('value' => 3, 'value2' => 1)
                 );

?><br>
```

How can I check both sides (value and value2) for duplicates and used my existing code?